# Insert text into cmd prompt through .bat file.

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Any idea on, how to insert text into a new cmd prompt window to continue the script?

e.g.

```
runas /user:adminuser cmd
```

opens up new cmd window. I want to insert the below using the batch file

```
c:
cd\temp\file\executefile.exe
del c:\temp
```

Comment: You can put the command in the clipboard, open a cmd prompt and be ready to paste it in.

Answer (score 0):

To print this on new windows cmd use this:

text.cmd:

```
@echo off
echo c: 
echo.
echo cd\temp\fichier\executefile.exe
echo. 
echo del c:\temp
pause
```

and use the command:

```
start text.cmd
```

You can use a file.cmd or file.bat it is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Create a batch file "C:\batch.bat" and insert these commands in each line

c:
c:\temp\file\executefile.exe
del c:\temp

and start this batch file using following command

> C:\> runas /user:adminuser C:\batch.bat

also you probably want to use following command to delete temp folder along with subfolder and files in temp. For that instead of `del c:\temp` use `echo y | rmdir /s c:\temp` in batch file

Answer (score 0):

```
runas /user:adminuser "cmd /C c: & cd\temp\file\executefile.exe & del c:\temp"
```

Previous line execute the commands and terminate the new cmd prompt window. If you want that the window remain after execute the commands, change `/C` by `/K`.

Answer (score -1):

To insert manually values into your command prompt when executing a batch script, use the following:

```
set /p var=
echo %var%
```

This will gather what you entered, then display it (or wathever you need).